# if cardNumberArray[0] == 4: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, compiler-errors

Just started learning python and I'm trying to print different things based on the user's input, however, when I run the code I get this error:

```
    if cardNumberArray[0] == 4:
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why when a number of 14-16 integers is inputted, the program says that cardNumberArray[0] is out of range, and why my program won't even print the different values given the below code.

```
cardNumber = input("what is the number?\n")
cardNumberArray = []

for i in cardNumberArray:
  cardNumberArray.append(int(i))
  print(f"Ith value: {cardNumberArray[i]}")

if cardNumberArray[0] == 4:
    print("VISA")
elif cardNumberArray[0] == 5:
  if cardNumberArray[1] == 1 or cardNumberArray[1] == 2 or cardNumberArray[1] == 3 or cardNumberArray[1] == 4 or cardNumberArray[1] == 4 or cardNumberArray[1] == 5:
    print("MASTERCARD")
elif cardNumberArray[0] == 3:
  if cardNumberArray[1] == 4 or cardNumberArray[1] == 7:
    print("AMEX")
else:
  print("INVALID")
```

Comment: you want to use `for i in cardNumber` instead of `for i in cardNumberArray:`

Comment: Or maybe ``for i in range(len(cardNumberArray)):``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is empty because you put the user's response on cardNumber variable.

Before using your Ifs, you must check if your array is not empty and if these indexes exist.

Answer (score 0):

The reason index 0 is out of range is because you haven't added any value to the list yet, and there are some more errors, like you need to convert the string into an integer, and instead of subscripting the value in the list, you need to subscript the index:

```
cardNumber = input("what is the number?\n")
cardNumberArray = [int(cardNumber)]

for i in range(len(cardNumberArray)):
  print(f"Ith value: {cardNumberArray[i]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments to the code to indicate the state of the array at various points:

```
cardNumber = input("what is the number?\n")
cardNumberArray = []  # array is empty

for i in cardNumberArray:  # array is still empty, so this loop does nothing
  cardNumberArray.append(int(i))  #  this never happens
  print(f"Ith value: {cardNumberArray[i]}")

# array is still empty since we never appended to it

if cardNumberArray[0] == 4:  # boom!
```

Maybe you want the loop to be something more like `for i in range(cardNumber)`?

Or maybe it should be `cardNumberArray = [int(input("what is the number?"))]`?  It's hard to discern what the intent of this code is; all I know is that as written the array is definitely always empty.

Answer (score 0):

All this can be done much easier:

```
cardNumber = input("what is the number?\n")
#cardNumberArray = []  <<-- don't need this

card_type = {
    '4' : 'VISA', '51' : 'MASTER', '52' : 'MASTER', '53' : 'MASTER',
   '54' : 'MASTER', '55' : 'MASTER', '34' : 'AMEX', '37' : 'AMEX'
}

cc_type = 'INVALID'
for ct in card_type :
    if cardNumber.startswith(ct) :
        cc_type = card_type[ct]
        break

print( cc_type )
```